# How do use LParam in Pinvoke GlobalGetAtomName

Tags: c#, winapi

I want to try to use Pinvoke to get a string from a WindowsFomrs.Message.

But GlobalGetAtomName requires an ushort and I have LParam which is an IntPtr.

How can I convert it?

```
[DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true, CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
static extern uint GlobalGetAtomName(ushort nAtom, StringBuilder lpBuffer, int nSize);

protected override void WndProc(ref Message m)
{

            Console.WriteLine("HWnd: " + m.HWnd.ToString());
            Console.WriteLine("LParam: " + m.LParam.ToString());
            Console.WriteLine("WParam: " + m.WParam.ToString());
            Console.WriteLine("Msg: " + m.Msg.ToString());
            int nSize = 514;
            StringBuilder AtomName = new StringBuilder(nSize);
            nSize = GlobalGetAtomName(m.LParam, AtomName, nSize);
            Console.WriteLine("String: " + AtomName);

    base.WndProc(ref m);
}
```

Comment: Sorry, is your question really nothing more than how do I cast IntPtr to ushort? If so, why not ask that? Of course, that's a duplicate too.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan I thought I was giving the minimum background. Sorry if that's confusing. Do you have an answer for me?

Comment: Well, er, cast it: `(ushort)m.LParam`

Comment: Oh good grief! It's that easy? I had another error which lead me to believe it was a cast issue. Feel very silly. Thanks for helping me out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cast the value to the desired type:

```
(ushort)m.LParam
```